# Is it possible to run GAE tests in Hudson?

Tags: google-app-engine, hudson, code-coverage, nose, nosetests

I have a suite of App Engine tests that are called using *nose*. When I run them from a terminal, every test completes successfully and all reports, like *coverage*, are generated.

However, if I try to call the same command from Hudson, I get the following failure from coverage:

```
nose.failure.Failure.runTest (from Failure)

Parent module 'coverage' not loaded
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/NoseGAE-0.1.7-py2.5.egg', '')
root: WARNING: Could not read datastore data from /tmp/nosegae.datastore
root: WARNING: Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named Image
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gaetestbed-0.12dev_r30-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/WebTest-1.2.1-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/WebOb-0.9.8-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/home/wraith/dev/projects/myapp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyYAML-3.09-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg', '')
root: DEBUG: Could not import "strop": Disallowed C-extension or built-in module
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

However, if I remove the call to *coverage*, my tests still fail.

I've succesfully run Python projects with *Hudson*. Is there a GAE nuance that's tripping me up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the environments when you run it manually to when you run it using hudson.

I suspect that the initialization happens within the .profile file. That is not called when Hudson spawns a shell. So either you put this initialization into the environment initialization or you call the .profile file manually within the effected build steps.

Comment: I don't have a .profile file, just .bashrc, whose variables are picked up just fine. Should I use .profile instead? Is this a system-wide file that is supposed to be stored in /etc/?

Comment: I've found that setting the explicit paths in each of the Hudson steps resolves any problems I have. For example, PYTHONPATH=.:$HOME/dev/modules/contrib:$HOME/dev/sdks/google_appengine. It's a bit cumbersome, but it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can avoid setting the environment variable for every build step. You can define environment variables in the main Hudson configuration. This environment variable will then be set for every job. That can also be done on node level (I use this approach). There is also a plugin, that gives you the ability to set variables on the Job level. Makes it a little bit easier than putting it in every step. :)